# Does typedef of a structure without tag creates distinct type each time it is used and if not why?

Tags: c, struct, language-lawyer, typedef

I'm wondering if you declare a structure like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
    //...
} name;
```

Then is it the case that every subsequent declaration of type 'name' will have  distinct type?

I'm wondering this because of (from standard) $6.7.2.3(p5):

> Two declarations of structure, union, or enumerated types which are in
>   different scopes or use different tags declare distinct types. **Each
>   declaration of a structure, union, or enumerated type which does not
>   include a tag declares a distinct type.**

And this $6.7.8(p3):

> In a declaration whose storage-class specifier is typedef, each
>   declarator defines an identifier to be a typedef name that denotes the
>   type specified for the identifier in the way described in 6.7.6.

And so something like this would be illegal (although clang will accept it):

```
typedef struct{
    int a, b;
} s;

void func(s);

int main()
{
   s a = {2, 2};
   s b = a;
}
```

If it is not the case please explain why?

Comment: I don't think it refers to that kind of declaration but when you use it like `struct { ... fields ... } variable;`.

Comment: What would it actually mean "declare distinct types"? What are the implications? I mean, what code will show the difference?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The multiple typedefs wouldn't be redundant (warning) but conflicting (error).

Comment: I'm not sure what you think about that code would be illegal.  There's only one declaration of the structure type.

Comment: But there are multiple declarations of structures. If you parse the rule as "Each declaration of (a (structure), (union), or (enumerated type))" rather than "Each declaration of a ((structure), (union), or (enumerated) type)" you could reach some strange conclusions, including `a` and `b` being different types.

Comment: `struct ...` is actually a _type specifier_. And `typedef` is a _type definition_. So the question lacks a foundation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Each declaration of a structure, union, or enumerated type which does not include a tag declares a distinct type.**

This line is saying that each time you declare *such a type*, that's a new type. It's not saying that each time you declare *a variable of such a type*, you declare a new type.

Your code only declares the type once, so it only creates one type.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are misunderstanding

> Each declaration of a structure, union, or enumerated type

This is a declaration of a structure type:

```
struct s1 {
    int a, b;
};
```

So is this

```
typedef struct {
    int a, b;
} s2;
```

It's also a declaration of a typedef.  And this is a declaration of a structure type AND an object:

```
struct {
    int a, b;
} o1;
```

This is NOT a declaration of structure type:

```
s2 o4, o5;
```

It is a declaration of two objects, each having structure type.  But the structure type is not declared here.

The Standard particularly says

> The presence of a *struct-declaration-list* in a struct-or-union-speciﬁer declares a new type, within a translation unit.

That *struct-declaration-list* is everything inside the braces.

So this one also is not a declaration of structure type:

```
struct s1 o2, o3;
```

Again, it declares objects, and gives them structure type, but because the *struct-declaration-list* is lacking it does not declare a type.